Transaction DECLINED by the Bank, Error:2000
I am Using Opayo PI payment gateway on my woocommerce website, A lot of my customers failed to Place order Due to Error : 2000 transaction DECLINED by the Bank. They have enough balance in their Card with no limit. out of 20 only 2 were able to place order. is there any issue with my payment gateway? looking for help.
I have contacted Opayo Support. They said it might be tbe issue from merchant Bank. I have contacted my Bank they said everything working perfectly fine at our end.

Is your 3DSecure and AVS/CV2 settings turned on in your MyOpayo portal? The decline normally comes from issuing bank, but give opayo support a call to investigate
